# SQL subquery returns no results

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display the number of employees working in the department with the most employees. But the query i have returns no output, it doesn't fail but no data is returned. I am using Oracle SQL developer but most forms of SQL should help.

Sorry I should have specified but this is for a class and the teacher wants only subqueries NOT joins.

```
select d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, count(e.employee_id)
from departments d, employees e
where d.department_id = (select max(count(employee_id)) from employees group by 
department_id)
group by d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

Comment: This is not a recursive query; the term is actually defined, and it has a different meaning, so you shouldn't be using it as a lay term.

Comment: Yes sorry about that I changed it to subquery.

Comment: Your query already joins employees to departments. (Using old syntax rather then modern explicit join syntax... kind of depressing that it's still being taught that way). Is even that join not allowed?

Comment: huh never though about that, but basically yes just no explicit joins if thats possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find a department ID which matches a number of employees; not the department those employees belong to.

If you're on 12c or higher you can use the row limiting clause:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.employee_id) as employee_count
from departments d
join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id, d.department_name
order by count(e.employee_id) desc
fetch first row only;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                EMPLOYEE_COUNT
------------- ------------------------------ --------------
           50 Shipping                                   45
```

If you can have ties and want to show all tied rows, change `only` to `with ties`; otherwise you'll get an indeterminate row from those that are tied.

In earlier versions the equivalent would be:

```
select department_id, department_name, employee_count
from (
  select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.employee_id) as employee_count
  from departments d
  join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
  group by d.department_id, d.department_name
  order by count(e.employee_id) desc
)
where rownum = 1;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                EMPLOYEE_COUNT
------------- ------------------------------ --------------
           50 Shipping                                   45
```

which is also indeterminate if there are ties.

To handle ties properly pre-12c, you can use a query similar to @Littlefoot's, but using `rank()`:

```
select department_id, department_name, employee_count
from (
  select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.employee_id) as employee_count,
    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from departments d
  join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
  group by d.department_id, d.department_name
  order by count(e.employee_id) desc
)
where rnk = 1;
```

... or use @TheImpaler's approach.

---

> the teacher wants subquery only

Always fun to have articifial restrictions... but you could do:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.employee_id) as employee_count
from departments d
join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id, d.department_name
having count(e.employee_id) = (
  select max(count(employee_id))
  from employees
  group by department_id
);
```

which will show ties; or

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.employee_id) as employee_count
from departments d
join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
where d.department_id in (
  select department_id
  from (
    select department_id
    from employees
    group by department_id
    order by count(employee_id) desc
  )
  where rownum = 1
)
group by d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

which won't, unless you change`rownum` to `rank()` again.

> no explicit joins if thats possible

If you aren't allowed *any* joins I suppose you could do:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name,
  (select count(e.employee_id)
    from employees e
    where e.department_id = d.department_id) as employee_count
from departments d
where d.department_id in (
  select department_id
  from (
    select department_id
    from employees
    group by department_id
    order by count(employee_id) desc
  )
  where rownum = 1
)
group by d.department_id, d.department_name;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                EMPLOYEE_COUNT
------------- ------------------------------ --------------
           50 Shipping                                   45
```

which is getting a bit ridiculous *8-)

Comment: Sorry I should have specified i know i can do it with joins but the teacher wants subquery only.

Comment: That last one looks just like what she was talking about having 2 subqueries to complete it

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
with
x as (
  select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(*) as tot
  from employees e
  join departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id
  group by d.department_id, d.department_name
),
y as (
  select max(tot) as t from x
)
select x.* from x join y on y.t = x.tot;
```

Extra feature (for the same price): if there are two departments tied in first place, this query will show you both.

Comment: This does work for me however i would like to see the department_name as well which is in the departments table

Comment: Added the department name, as requested.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified i know i can do it with joins but the teacher wants subquery only

Answer (score 1):

Based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> with rnk as
  2    (select deptno,
  3            count(*) cnt,
  4            row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) rn
  5     from emp
  6     group by deptno
  7    )
  8  select d.deptno, d.dname, r.cnt
  9  from dept d join rnk r on r.deptno = d.deptno
 10  where r.rn = 1;

    DEPTNO DNAME                 CNT
---------- -------------- ----------
        30 SALES                   6

SQL>
```

with source data being

```
SQL> select deptno, count(*)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno;

    DEPTNO   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
        30          6
        20          3
        10          3

SQL>
```